# C: What the mistake in my prog?

Tags: c

This is simple program with files in C.

Input Name of person and ID to file text.

But is not working fine, and will happy to help with code.

My function malloc is ok?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void person();

void main(){

    person();
}

void person(){

    FILE *file;
    char *str;
    int i,id;

    file=fopen("personid.txt","w");

    if(!file)
    {
        puts("Error");
        exit(1);
    }

    str=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        puts("Enter name:");
        gets(str);
        puts("Enter you ID:");
        scanf("%d",&id);
        fprintf(file,"%s - %9d\n",str,id);
    }

    free(str);
    fclose(file);

}
```

Comment: Could you define "not working fine"? Does it not compile? Does it run slow? Does it segfault? Does it print out the wrong data? Does it skin cats? We can't know unless you tell us.

Comment: You're only allocating enough space to store a pointer to `char`, which won't be enough for the name.

Comment: You are allocating a string the size of a `char*` which is probably big enough to hold 3 characters.

Comment: @SethCarnegie on x64 enough for 7 characters :-)

Comment: @rekire hence "probably"

Comment: @Kitsune now working fine the print out in data file is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your memory allocation is wrong it should be like this:

```
str=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*count_of_chars);
```

Remember to set a value for `count_of_chars`.

Comment: Though `sizeof(char)*` is redundant because `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1

Comment: I think that is a stil question you could also replace `char` by `wchar_t` which could return 2 in case of UTF-16 or 4 in case of UTF-32.

Comment: if i created the char *str, but not do malloc, what happens in fact?

Comment: In case that `str` has the value null. You'll get a segmentation fault or an access violent.

Comment: @engc actually it has an undefined value and you cause undefined behaviour by even using it

Answer (score 2):

Two problems.  First of all, you need to declare your `person` function above your main one.  So:

```
void person();
void main() {
    ...
}

void person() {
    ...
}
```

Should work fine.  Second of all, the way you are using malloc, you are only going to get one `char *` of memory.  You need to do:

```
str=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*stringLength);
```

where `stringLength` is the maximum amount of characters you want in your string.

Comment: There is a prototype for `person()` in the question.

Comment: ok thanks.but have problem with the fprintf to files, the loop for is not working fine and i am not found the problem in prog.

Comment: @rekire woops, I must have scrolled down the code without realizing it.

Comment: yes. the print in file is not name - id \n name - id etc. you can running program please and understand me? thanks.